# Apache Worker and APC user cache

Tags: apc, worker, spdy, mod-fcgid, opcache

Anybody tried APCu with ZendOPcache in MPM Worker ?
I went into problems with MPM Worker-APC but I found the article https://engineyard.zendesk.com/entries/26902267

My target is to achieve Apache MPM Worker with mod_fcgi [ for mod_spdy to work ] and ZendOPcache with APCu ( user cache ) and Varnish on top.
I run Centos 6.4 over KVM.

Any oppinion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am a Jetty developer, but since you asked for any opinion, here you go.

A very alternative option is to run [Jetty with its FastCGI module](https://webtide.com/jetty-9-1-4-open-sources-fastcgi-proxy/) (this link is actually WordPress run by Jetty and with Chrome it's served via SPDY too - via [ALPN](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2013/03/20/alpn.html)).

[Jetty](http://eclipse.org/jetty) is a Java server well known for its SPDY support (the only server that does [transparent SPDY push](https://webtide.com/jetty-spdy-push-improvements/)), and recently for its FastCGI support too; it has a small memory footprint and it's highly scalable because it is completely asynchronous.

With [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) in the front (mostly for SSL offloading) we are very satisfied of the setup.